# Capture values for firebase transaction

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I capture values when creating a firebase transaction? [Even the code example for transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/save-data#save_data_as_transactions) inside the firebase docs doesn't work, it gives me the following errors:

```
Variable 'score' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
Variable 'email' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't there be an option to pass data like it's done for [Future onCompletion callbacks?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/future.html#oncompletion) I'm using the latest firebase c++ framework by the way (4.0.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by switching to the aws c++ sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Wen defining lambdas, an empty capture list `[]` captures nothing.
So the example is clearly wrong.
It should be:

1. `[&]` - capture everything by refrence
2. `[=]` - capture everything by copy
3. `[email, &score]` - capture named variables: email by copy, score by reference
4. ... other combinations

Source: [Cpp reference - Lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: It's actually not a lambda function (I wish it would be), it just looks like one. The reason for this (as described in the firebase docs): "Note that we can't capture this value in the [] because std::function is not supported by our minimum compiler spec (which is pre C++11)." [(see this link)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/google-signin#register_a_callback_on_a_futurewzxhzdk12wzxhzdk13)